# Cors issue with third party api

Tags: javascript, http, cors, fetch-api

I am struggle with getting data from third party api on browser. 'https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarkets'

I set `mode:'no-cors'` as option because it seems the response header does not include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. But `mode: no-cors` does not allow me to access to the data.

```
function callApi({ url }) {

  return fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response) {
    }

    return response.json()
  })
  .then(response => {
    const camelizedJson = camelizeKeys(response)

    return Object.assign({},
      normalize(camelizedJson),
    )
  })
```

}

The response returns `type: opaque` like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3VlL.png) and response headers is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaWwE.png)

I believe `mode: no-cors` works like sending GET request from HTML img tag so I can not use the information.

Is there any way to access to the third party API whose response header does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? How am I supposed to call third party public api?

If you have any ideas to fix this problem, please let me know! Thank you

Comment: if third party doesn't issue CORS headers, there's no way to bypass this - except by using your own **server** to make the request, as server to server requests do not need CORS headers